# show $|x^3 - y^3| \leq 3|x-y|\max \{x^2, y^2\}$ for $x,y \in\mathbb R.$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

I've split this question into three cases:
when $x>y,$ when $y>x$ and when $x=y$.

when $x=y$ the inequality reduces to $0\leq 0$ which is true.

when $x>y$, I've managed to reduce the inequality to $x^3 - y^3 \leq 3x^3 - 3yx^2.$ But I don't know how to proceed from here and prove this inequality is true.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Your equivalent for $x>y$ is only true if also $|x|>|y|.$ For example, if $x=1,y=-2,$ then $y^2>x^2.$

Answer (score 2):

By the identity $x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$ and the fact that $x^2\leq \max(x^2,y^2)$, $xy\leq \max(x^2,y^2)$ and $y^2\leq \max(x^2,y^2)$
$$
|x^3 - y^3| \leq |x-y|\,|x^2+xy+y^2|
\\\leq 3\,|x-y|\,\max(x^2,y^2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

From where you were, you just needed to factor out the $3x^2$ to finish it off :)
(And as pointed out, use the modulus bars throughout)